# jQuery Cut Image on Client Side

Tags: jquery

Are there any chance to cut/croop image on client side ? I search web for plugins but every plugin require server side scripts to save image - and I do not want this. I just want to crop image like:

```
var my_image = jQuery('.my_class .my_img img');
var my_image_height = jQuery('.my_class .my_img img').height();

if ( my_image_height > 223){
    ... // and what I can do in here. Is there any change for that ? 
        // Best thing will be cut image by X pixels from bottom :)    
}
```

Some tips ? or this is just impossible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, but it is not simple. You must load it to canvas, crop it, and then set it as src of particular img element. Or you can simulate crop with CSS. Do not use img element, but div for example, and then set background-image properties in suitable way.

Comment: background-image ... this can work ... I will try it but first must little rebuild carousel layout

Comment: @Wordica Yes. CSS approach will be simplier, with just few code improvements.

Comment: Yep, the most basic solutions are always best :D Thanks, I recreate layout and now it's ok.

Comment: Ps. Sometimes for few hours "You" create large script and on second day solution takes two lines ;)